# Trailing slash mod_rewrite rule for certain subfolders

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get a trailing slash mod_rewrite rule to work for only certain subfolders.

I have article URLs like ////. For example an article URL may be /news/role-playing-games/new-roleplaying-game-released/.  Sometimes, for whatever reason, people try the URLs without the trailing slash and they get a 404. I would like instead for apache to add a trailing slash to only the URLs that match certain subfolders.

I tried this rule, but it does not work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(news|reviews|tutorials|guides)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^((news|reviews|tutorials|guides)/[^/]+/[^/]+)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

I assumed that the url structure you gave is the only one.

Comment: I think it should work now. Tested it.here http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/